# Buffering roads (<100m - 200m -400m->400m) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, reclassify, buffer

[image: i want to buffer road (<100m - 200m -400m->400m) i have problum with <and> how can i use <and> like this photo?]

I want to buffer road (<100m - 200m -400m->400m) I have problem with  how can I use  like this photo?

I dont know use any type of buffer. How can I solve my problem?

I don't know  will be use in multi ring buffer or euclidean distance or how can I solve?

Comment: Have you tried the [Multiple Ring Buffer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm)? If not, I recommend trying it, and either way if it does not meet your requirement can you describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: in mulitiple ring bufer cant accept <and> i tried but i dont know why and in more thesis the reasercher used it but i dont know how use the <and> value i dont know they used reclasify or which tools

Comment: did you saw the photo?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to merge two of the rings into a single multi-part polygon?  If so, just add a field to code like that and then Dissolve on it.  The Picture just looks like the result of a Multiple Ring Buffer, but you did not tell us how you came by it.

Comment: this photo is not  is not my result, i have the the project and must use the same tool to the same result for roads and river and buliding .i have a thesis about land fill site selction

Comment: Have you tried the [Multiple Ring Buffer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm)?  Are you saying that you want to merge two of the rings into a single multi-part polygon? If so, just add a field to give the two rings the same code value and then Dissolve on it.

Comment: in mulitiple ring buffer can not accept the symbul >400 and   >100

Comment: Run Multiple Ring Buffer to create whatever buffer sizes you want, then Add Field perhaps called CODE, edit the buffers to give the two buffers you want merged the same value, and then Dissolve on CODE.

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the buffer and the erase tool. Create a 100m buffer & a 500m buffer. Than erase the 100m from the 500m and you have the feature 100-500m. Later you can merge all together.